# How do I add an alert dialog to Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I am looking to add an alert dialog similar to the example below upon install of a Google Workspace App.  How can I do this? I don't see anything in the Google Apps Script documentation for this.

[image]

Comment: There is  an alert in the [UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html).  If that doesn't meet your needs then there is [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) for creating custom dialogs.

Comment: What do you mean by "upon install of a GoogleWorkspace App"? Are you creating a Workspace add-on (uses the CardService) or an Editor Add-on (Uses the Class Ui)? Also please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: When I say "upon install of a Google Workspace App", I mean when someone first downloads it and the application icon appears on their right hand navigator for the first time. We have a Workspace add-on (CardService).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in Google Workspace Add-on.